# How can I fix this problem I have with OpenMP's built-in vector reduction?

Tags: openmp, linear-algebra, reduction

I am developing my own implementation of sparse BLAS functions for CSC storage formats. To do so, I created the following data structure:

```c
typedef struct SparseMatrixCSC {
  int m;            // Number of rows
  int n;            // Number of columns
  int nnz;          // Number of stored values
  double *val;      // Stored values
  int *row_idx;     // Row indices of stored values
  int *col_start;   // Column j contains values with indices in col_start[j]:(col_start[j+1]-1)
} SparseMatrixCSC;
```

Then, I wanted to use OpenMP in order to parallelize the matrix-vector product (SpMV). I used different approaches to circumvent race conditions.

First, I used atomic operations as follows:

```c
void dcscmv_atomic(SparseMatrixCSC *A, double *x, double *y) {
  for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) y[i] = 0.;
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int j=0; j<A->n; j++) {
    for (int ii=A->col_start[j]; ii<A->col_start[j+1]; ii++) {
      #pragma omp atomic
      y[A->row_idx[ii]] += A->val[ii] * x[j];
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine, but it is terribly slow and actually rather yields slowdown than speedup.

Second, I tried to use OpenMP's built-in vector reduction feature as follows:

```c
void dcscmv_builtin_array_reduction(SparseMatrixCSC *A, double *x, double *y) {
  for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) y[i] = 0.;
  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:y[:A->m])
  for (int j=0; j<A->n; j++) {
    for (int ii=A->col_start[j]; ii<A->col_start[j+1]; ii++) {
      y[A->row_idx[ii]] += A->val[ii] * x[j];
    }
  }
}
```

While this code compiles correctly, it works correctly with one single thread, but it leads to a segmentation fault when using multiple threads.

Third, since I could not get OpenMP's built-in vector reduction to work, I tried coding my own reduction as follows:

```c
void dcscmv_array_reduction_from_scratch(SparseMatrixCSC *A, double *x, double *y) {
  for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) y[i] = 0.;
  double *YP;
  #pragma omp parallel 
  {
    int P = omp_get_num_threads();
    int p = omp_get_thread_num();
    #pragma omp single
    {
      YP = (double*)mkl_malloc(A->m * P * sizeof(double), sizeof(double));
      for (int i=0; i<A->m*P; i++) YP[i] = 0.;
    }
    #pragma omp for
    for (int j=0; j<A->n; j++) {
      for (int ii=A->col_start[j]; ii<A->col_start[j+1]; ii++) {
        YP[p * A->m + A->row_idx[ii]] += A->val[ii] * x[j];
      }
    }
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i=0; i<A->m; i++) {
      for (int p=0; p<P; p++) {
        y[i] +=  YP[A->m * p + i];
      }
    }
  }
  mkl_free(YP);
}
```

This function worked, but still gave me a slowdown, although not as bad as with `dcscmv_atomic`.

I still have hope that if I get `dcscmv_builtin_vector_reduction` to work, I might be able to get some speedup. Hence, my question is: what is wrong with the way I implemented the vector reduction in `dcscmv_builtin_vector_reduction`, and how can I get rid of this segmentation fault?

I tried to apply OpenMP's buit-in vector reduction feature with `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:y[:A->m])`, but although the code compiled, it results in a segmentation fault at execution with multiple threads.

Comment: I found the problem. My code for ```dcscmv_builtin_array_reduction``` does work, but only for small arrays. OpenMP sets an upper limit on the supported array size for array reduction, see here in Fortran: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Max-array-size-for-reduction-in-OpenMP/m-p/1037990#M112280

Comment: The problem is solved by setting the environment variable KMP_STACKSIZE to a larger value.

Comment: Better use OMP_STACKSIZE rather than the Intel-specific env variable. The background is that the compiler wants to allocate space for the array on the stacks of each thread. This stack is by default very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the indirect addressing which makes the loop not trivially parallel. As you have noticed, simple solutions don't work or are slow. Two ways out.

1. You can give each thread its own output vector and then merge them in the end.
2. Instead of a column-based algorithm, use a row-based one. Then each component of the output is independently computable and therefore parallel. Yes, I know that you are storing your matrix by column, but even then it is possible. You can probably find an algorithm for the Transpose product with a CRS matrix. That's basically it.

Comment: I know the indirect addressing makes the loop non-trivially parallelizable, that's precisely why I want to use reduction. Otherwise, I would not need it. But I do not understand why the built-in vector reduction does not work. My understanding is  that, under the hood, when doing ```#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:y[:A->m])```, openMP should allocate a new array for each thread and sum them in the end. I know parallelizing a CSR SpMV would be better. But MKL manages to enable multithreading for CSC too, it does not scale as well as CSR, but it still gives a little bit of speedup.

Comment: The `reduction(+:y[:A->m])` reduction ought to work. But I have seen compilers given crashing code because of the problem of internal allocation. Can you try a different compiler? I'm using the Intel compiler with LLVM backend, which means that anything else LLVM-based ought to work too, if the version is new enough.

Comment: I use icc 2021.6 on Linux, which does support OpenMP 4.5+. As it turns out, it does work, but only for small arrays.

Comment: I wonder if that's because of stack limitations. Btw, Intel has progressed quite a bit and the "classic" compiler which you are using is no longer developed. Upgrade to 2023.1 (with .2 out or coming soon) if you can.

Comment: Yes, stack limitation is exactly what it is. I mentioned it as a comment to my initial post, it can be adjusted through either of the KMP_STACKSIZE or OMP_STACKSIZE environment variables. Now it works. I don't have a say on which compiler we use, but I'll let my manager know. Thank you.